# Convert java (with params) to exe

Tags: java, batch-file

Using Eclipse I've created a Java project with one single class that needs an argument.
In my PC where I have Java installed, I run this:

```
java -jar test.jar %arg1%
```

I can put this in a batch file and it runs successfully. The batch has the next lines:

```
echo off
set /p arg1=Enter path where file is:
java -jar test.jar %arg1%
pause
```

How can I generate this but in an exe file?
I need that the exe file ask for a path and execute the jar even thought the PC doesn't have Java

P.D. In some forums it's suggests to use launch4j but it doesn't allow dinamical params.

Comment: if your app has a GUI, you could prompt the path in a dialog at startup

Comment: *even though the PC doesn't have Java* -> you can't execute **Java** *without* **Java**

Comment: There are several JVM wrappers, just search the internet. Question is - is it worth the effort? What's wrong with having a batch file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lino true, but wrappers like launch4j can proivde an embeded java installer

Comment: If you don't want to install Java on the computer that is going to run the application and if you're hell bent on creating your app as an **.exe** executable file then....create it in a language other than Java. On a PC, how does one run, view, listen to, do anything without first installing the appropriate drivers, applications, hardware, etc?

Comment: To answer to all: it's only a Java class that takes a .txt file, does some convertions and generates other .txt file. There isn't a GUI.

Comment: On the other side, wrappers like launch4j didn't work because the args should be defined before generating the .exe